# Vaadin app build with gradle installs node in production

Tags: gradle, vaadin, production

I've been playing with vaadin icw gradle. When I build the application with the -Pvaadin.productionMode and then execute the jar, in the logging I see the FrontendTools installing node.

Based on the documentation I would expect the Java app to serve all js, and there needn't be a dependency/installation needed of node at runtime.

```
2022-04-05 20:25:19.344  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-04-05 20:25:19.351  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.xxx.xxxx.configuration.Application   : Started Application in 4.142 seconds (JVM running for 4.475)
2022-04-05 20:25:19.431  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.a.b.c.data.generator.DataGenerator     : Generating demo data
2022-04-05 20:25:19.431  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.a.b.c.data.generator.DataGenerator     : ... generating 100 Configuration entities...
2022-04-05 20:25:19.459  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.v.flow.server.frontend.FrontendTools   : Couldn't find node. Installing Node and npm to /home/myuser/.vaadin.
2022-04-05 20:25:19.469  INFO 8 --- [           main] NodeInstaller                            : Installing node version v16.14.2
```

Is there a property or flag I need setting? The examples are mostly maven based perhaps I need to do a little bit more in gradle?

I build like so:
`gradle -Pvaadin.productionMode`
Which runs: `defaultTasks("clean", "vaadinBuildFrontend", "build")`

Comment: You are right that there is no need for node installation at runtime. You can compare your setup to the https://github.com/vaadin/base-starter-spring-gradle.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Correctly done production build should not do that. Have you checked documentation for jar packaged production build here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/guide/start/gradle/#production

Answer (score 1):

After eliminating and checking all differences between the base gradle example and my own project:

The culprit was using the `com.vaadin.exampledata.ExampleDataGenerator` to setup some bogus data.
If I don't, node won't install ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Not sure if that is a bug or a feature.

Comment: A related ticket: https://github.com/vaadin/starters/issues/70.